# React Native text input mask

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

We're developing program on React Native, and I have a question. How to make a text input mask for ZIP code and mobile phone number via React Native?

Here's a sample:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Comment: You want the "fields" to be visible even after the user starts typing?

Comment: Maybe there are modules written in objc or swift which you could export to react-native.

Comment: Nabn, yes, I want visible fields.

Comment: Manetsus, thanks for editing. I don't have error message. I just need to make fields via RN like in a sample above

Answer (score 6):

Check out this library.
https://github.com/wix/react-native-ui-lib

(or directly this: https://github.com/wix/react-native-ui-lib#masked-input)

It allows you to render custom masked input in any format you want.

You can use it as follow: (this is an example for a phone number)

```
import {MaskedInput} from 'react-native-ui-lib'

// in your render...
<MaskedInput
  renderMaskedText={this.renderMaskedInput}
  caretHidden
  keyboardType={'numeric'}
/>

renderMaskedInput(value) {

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>
      {value.substr(0, 3)} - {value.substr(3, 10)}
      <Text>
    <View>
  );
}
```

Comment: please post a complete answer, instead of making it dependent of an external content that might go offline sometime. The goal here is to help users, even in the future, that might have the same question.

Comment: The link is to a readme of an existing component in a lib for react native. 
If this one goes offline, I assume the component will not be relevant as well.
But I can elaborate

Comment: So, put details on your answer - what is this component? how does it work? how can it solve the questioner's issue? Your answer should be complete enough without the link... check [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: added more info (: hopes this helps better.

Comment: Please add more info (: from 2020

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using this library to use a custom mask on TextInput component https://github.com/akinncar/react-native-mask-text

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29806279)